# Replicate modified data on different database

Tags: java, database, jpa, jms

I would like to ask for an starting point of what technology or framework to research.

What I need to accomplish is the following:

We have a Java EE 6 application using JPA for persistance; we would like to use a primary database as some sort of scratchpad, where users can insert/delete records according to the tasks they are are given. Then, at the end of the day an administrator will do some kind of check on their work approving or disapproving it. If he approves the work, all changes will be done permanent and the primary database will be synced - replicated to another one (for security reasons). Otherwise, if administrator do not approve changes they will be rolled back.

Now here I got two problems to figure out:

First.- Is it possible to rollback a bunch of JPA operations done through a certain amount of time?

Second.- Trigger the replication (This can be done by RDBMS engines) process by code.
Now, if RDBMS replication is not possible (maybe because of client requirement) we would need a sync framework for JPA as a backup. I was looking at some JMS solutions, however not clear about the exact process or how to make them work on JPA.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, your design steps are having too much risk on loosing data. What I understand that you are talking about holding data in memory until admin approves/reject it. You must think about a disaster scenario and saving your data in that case.

Rather this problem statement is more inclined towards a workflow design, where the

> 1. data is entered by one entity, it is persisted.
> 2. Other entity approve/> reject the data.
> 3. All the approved data is further replicated to next database.

All these three steps could be implemented in 3 modules, backed by a persistent storage/ JMS technology. Depending on how real time, each of these steps needs to be; you could think of an elegant design to accomplish this in a cost effective manner.

Answer (score 1):

- Add a "workflow state" column to your table. States: Wait for approval, approved, replicated
- Persist your data normally using JPA (state: wait for approval)
- Approver approves: Update using JPA, change to approved state

As for the replication

- In the approve method you could replicate the data synchronously to the other database (using JPA)
- You could copy as well the approved data to another table, and use some RDBMS functionality to have the RDBMS replicate the data of that table
- You could as well send a JMS message. At the end of the day a job reads the queue and persists the data into the other database

Anyway I suggest using a normal RDBMS cluster with synchronous replication. In that scenario you don't have to develop a self-made replication scheme, and you always have a copy of your data. You always have the workflow state.